# Remove part of URL using PHP (Zend FrameWork)

Tags: php, zend-framework

my link is like this :

```
http://website.com/test1/test2/public/books/detail/page_id/number/page/2
```

I want to remove page and 2 and convert it to :

```
http://website.com/test1/test2/public/books/detail/page_id/number
```

I can define last part of URL with :

```
$uri = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
$part = basename($uri);
```

or define another part like this :

```
$parts = Explode('/', $uri);
    $id2 = $parts[count($parts) - 2];
    $id1 = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
```

but I have problems to remove that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$uri = $this->serverUrl(true);    
$parts = Explode('/page/', $uri);
```

the $parts[0] will be the good link you want

Answer (score 0):

I think, for your case, this should be in your controller:

```
$url = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl() .
"books/detail/page_id/" . $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id');
```

PS: Syntax will be different if you are in a view script, in which case you should create a view helper anyway or you can do it in controller and assign to view.